# export selected fields from a body of an email to .csv file

Tags: javascript, php, html, shopify, outlook-2010

I have a shopify website that has a Request a Catalog page where users post there information and I receive it in email Outlook 2010 in this format in the body:

- First Name: John
- Last Name: Doe
- Email: johndoe@email.com
- Address: 1234 address rd.
- City: CA
- Zip Code: 12345

Is there a way I could export those fields from multiple submissions into one master.csv file so I dont have to constantly copy and paste the information indiviually?

Comment: Yes... There are many ways to do it.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? What does the shopify documentation detail about this?

Comment: Just trying to get ideas and see which way the best approach would be.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at the free Microsoft Add-In Power Query (from Excel 2010) for extracting mails from your Exchange account directly into Excel.

You will have to define your queries in order to get the data you want; however, what you are asking for seems quite basic and achievable with limited knowledge of Power Query.

Have a look at the [Introduction to Microsoft Power Query for Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605) page.